# Multiple if statement in VB for ArcGIS

Tags: vbscript, arcgis, shapefile

I have a shape-file with two columns (Thirri_2a and Thirri 2b) both are filled with positiv and negativ double values. No i want to summarize both in a new column named "Thirri". Therefore i used a if statement to check true values (not equal to 0).

```
Dim x As Double
If (([Thirri_2a] = 0) And ([Thirri_2b] = 0)) Then
 x = 0
ElseIf (([Thirri_2a] = 0) And ([Thirri_2b] <> 0)) Then
 x = [Thirri_2b] 
ElseIf (([Thirri_2a] <> 0) And ([Thirri_2b] = 0)) Then
 x = [Thirri_2a] 
Else (([Thirri_2a] <> 0) And ([Thirri_2b] <> 0)) 
 x = (( [Thirri_2a] + [Thirri_2b] )/2)
End If
```

ArcGIS gives me the wonderful Errormessage:
"Error 999999"

Comment: Assuming that ArcGIS uses VBScript (not VBA) as its scripting language, delete the type spec (As Double).

Comment: Ok i tried this before but it also gives the same error

Comment: Then make sure you can use `[Thirri_2b]` to access the variable. [] are legal in VBScript, but used to allow non-standard letters in variable names.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with that code other than the type specifier as @Ekkehard.Horner notes, but that entire block should go in the `Pre-logic Script Code` block.

In the following field, which should be labelled `Thirri =`, just put `x`.